# Simulating a "Card Layout" when using Flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm having a rather complex problem here. I'd like to make a Layout in CSS featuring multiple **Layers** which means basically having multiple `<div>` elements stacked ontop of each other (or at least make it look like this) and only the top one is visible.

In many other GUI Environements this is known as a **Card Layout**.

So the plan was:

- Create all `<div class='layer'>` elements in one parent `<div class='container'>` element
- Make them have `display: none` initially
- invoke `$.show()` or `$.hide()` to show or hide them

**HTML:**

```
<div id="containerOne">
    <div  class="layer a"></div>
    <div class="layer b">
        <div  class="inner b1"></div>
    </div>
    <div  class="layer c"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#containerOne {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
}

#containerOne .layer {
    display : none;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.a {    
    background: green;
}

.b {
    background: orange;
}

.b1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: yellow;
}

.c {
    background: blue;
}
```

This works at first since the elements will not have any space reserved on the page initially and will only occupy space when shown.

Now if i have a nested element *inside* a Layer and i want it to have a size of **50% x 50%** this also works well: *Even if the layer div is set to `display: none` initially*.

Now by default my Container div is set to `display: block` and all the size calculation seems to work fine and here's where my problem begins:

I need the Container div to have `display: flex` to take advantage of the *Flexbox* features of modern browsers. Instead of setting a fixed width for my *Layers* i now configure them to have `flex: 1` so they grow to the full size of the container.

This also works as expected. With one exception: The nested Element that should have a size of **50% x 50%** won't have a size at all. Debugging this in JavaScript shows that this is because at the moment the *Layers* are created they will all have a size of **0 x 0** and will first get their size assigned when they are shown by `$.show()`.

What i would expect is that once they are shown, the nested element will grow to its **50% x 50%** size but it doesn't.

- Is there anything i can do about it? (good solutions and *back-hack-workaround* solutions).

I also made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CN7e8/1/) to demonstrate the problem and to play around with.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're expecting to happen *should* happen, but it doesn't (in Chrome) due to a bug. It actually works correctly in Firefox.

Here's a simplified version of your testcase with no dynamic changes:
 http://jsfiddle.net/CN7e8/4/

This behavior was actually recently changed in the flexbox spec, to the behavior you're expecting. The issue is that your 50% height on `b1` is resolving against an auto-height element (the flex item, `b`) and Chrome is treating that auto-height as an invalid percent basis, even though the auto-height can actually be resolved to the container's height. (It'll become the container's height due to the default `align-items: stretch` on the flex container, which makes auto-height flex items take on the container's height).

For reference, the spec change to clarify this is mentioned under ISSUE 3, part (a), in this post:
   http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Mar/0350.html

ANYWAY. To work around the Chrome bug, you can't have an auto-height on your flex item `b`, given that you're depending on it being a percent-basis. You have to give it an explicit height, e.g. `height:100%` (which more directly resolves against the container's height). Here's your fiddle, with that changed: http://jsfiddle.net/CN7e8/5/

Comment: (edit: my answer initially said there were issues with the "$" being recognized in Firefox; turns out that's just because my NoScript addon was blocking scripts from jquery. :))